# Get varible to server.js from client side

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Im using Socket.io to get the active users, currently I'm able to asign the username with a string but I want to transfer a variable called name to my server side aswell..

Server.js

```
var io =  require("socket.io")(http);
var users = [];

io.use((socket, next) => {
  users[socket.id] = {
    username: "Filip" // I want this string to be my variable name
  };
  console.log(users);
  return next();
});
```

Site.html

```
var io = io("http://localhost:3000");
var name =  <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['displayname']); ?>;
io.emit("beautiful_name", name);
```

I tried to transfer the name with emit but I wasn't able to do anything that worked I'm afraid, anyone else know how I get my emit to work, or know any other solution?

This is what Im trying to acheive:

```
var io =  require("socket.io")(http);

var users = [];
io.on("beautiful_name", function (name){
var clientname = name;
});
io.use((socket, next) => {
  users[socket.id] = {
    username: clientname 
  };
  console.log(clientname);
  return next();
});
```

Comment: are you sure you include socket.io properly on your client side

Comment: yes I think so:), il add it

Answer (score 1):

You're listening to a global event on the server, I.E. listening to the IO instead of a socket. Also, you use `users[socket.id]` to append the user to the user array, if you want to have a key to access the user list make it an object and keep your code the same. Another issue with your code is that you are accessing the socket variable without ever initializing it, put all of your socket code in `io.on("connection")` to be able to communicate directly with the socket instead of with the server as a whole. Try this method, I believe it should work

```
var io =  require("socket.io")(http);

var users = {};
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("beautiful_name", function (name){
       var clientname = name;
       users[socket.id] = {
            username: clientname
       }
       console.log(clientname);
    });
  });
function getNumberOfUsers() {
   return Object.keys(users).length;
}
```

I hope this helps, if you need clarification please let me know.

Comment: Ah makes sense, thanks alot for your explanation, now everything works!!

Comment: Seems like this works to make my name appear however it doesn't include counting active users which (socket, next) does

Comment: If you want to do that do `Object.keys(users).length` it will return the number of users connected if this works accepting the answer would be greatly appreciated :). And to keep the active user list accurate listen for `socket.on("disconnect")` and in the callback do `delete users[socket.id]` to remove said user from the list

Comment: already got the disconnect done but how do I implent object keys user length into your answer?:)

Comment: See new answer, created a function to implement the `Object.keys` to get number of users